# How to programmatically select a parent checkbox after the user has selected the child checkbox? (using Angular Material)

Tags: angular, checkbox

I needed a function where when the user selects the parent checkbox, the child checkbox is automatically selected as well. This is actually working. Yet I was struggling to implement the following: when one of the child checkboxes gets selected, the parent checkbox should also be selected. Can anyone help me with this?

**HTML - child checkbox:**

```
<div>
  <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let subitem of subitems" [value]="subitem" [checked]="subitem.selected"
    (change)="onChangechild(filter)">{{
    subitem.value
    }}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**HTML - parent checkbox:**

```
<div>
  <mat-checkbox  [value]="stage1" [checked]="stage1.selected" (change)="onChange($event)">
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
onChangechild(stage1) {
  stage1.selected = this.subitems.some(subitem => subitem.selected);
 }

 onChange(event: any) {
   this.subitems.forEach(subitem => {
     subitem.selected = event.checked;
   });
}
```

Comment: Solving this problem generically is complicated. Please see Angular Material's solution in the official example here: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-checklist